# Add custom icon to the shape list in Spotfire

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence, spotfire, business-objects

I want to add a custom icon in the icon list for more meaningfull shapes

[image]

Comment: Currently not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed, as @Andrew Pruet has suggested, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this. however if you're really invested in custom icons, you could create a customization using the SDK, granting the ability to have as many icons or even images as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the `R` programming language, this is doable.

See my post in a related [Tibco's idea portal](https://ideas.tibco.com/ideas/SPF-I-5123).

This particular use case draws a drilling rig as the custom marker.

Special thanks to the [R Core team](https://www.R-project.org/), [tidyverse](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse), and [sf](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) authors.

```r
# `data_raw` is a spatial data frame with latitude and longitude; in this case in CRS 4326
data_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(data_raw, coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Munge default geometry object, which is a point
# First, get it out as vectors
lng_lat <- lapply(data_sf$geometry, as.vector)

# The key _drawing_ function for a drilling rig; a minimalist artist I am, as you'll see :)
draw_rig <- function(mid_x, step_x, mid_y, step_y) {
  max_y <- min_y <- mid_y - 3 * step_y
  
  min_x <- mid_x - 3 * step_x

  max_x <- mid_x + 3 * step_x

  rig <- sf::st_linestring(
    cbind(
      c(min_x, mid_x, mid_x + step_x, mid_x - step_x, mid_x + 2 * step_x, mid_x + step_x, mid_x - 2 * step_x, mid_x + 2 * step_x, max_x),
      c(min_y, mid_y, mid_y - step_y, mid_y - step_y, mid_y - 2 * step_y, mid_y - step_y, mid_y - 2 * step_y, mid_y - 2 * step_y, max_y))
    )

  return(rig)
}

# Apply _drawing_ function; step_x and step_y are set based on personal taste and affect the size of marker in map
lng_lat_sf <- purrr::map(
  lng_lat,
  ~ draw_rig (
    mid_x = .x[[1]],
    step_x = 0.167 / 2,
    mid_y = .x[[2]],
    step_y = 0.334 / 2
  )
)

# Convert back to sf object
data_sf$geometry <- sf::st_as_sfc(lng_lat_sf)

# Save as .shp file for .dxp import
sf::st_write(
  data_sf,
  "rigs.shp",
  driver = "ESRI Shapefile",
  delete_layer = TRUE
)
```